# Is there a way to print Ruby function source, like JavaScript's Function#toString / toSource?

Tags: ruby

I can print a function's contents as a string in JS:

```
(function (x) { alert(x + 'y'); }).toString()
> "function (x) { alert(x + 'y'); }"
```

Is there something similar with Ruby?